# Need to access a sharepoint link from a .net application such that i can list all the documents present in that SP link

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Unable to access the SP link from .net application using VS 2019

I tried this piece of code but have not much help from it. Please help me with the correct method for it.

```
string siteCollectionUrl = "https://reedelsevier.sharepoint.com/"
string username = username@gmail.com
string password = "XXXXX
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteCollectionUrl)
SecureString secureString = new SecureString()
password.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);                  
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, secureString)
Site site = ctx.Site;
ctx.Load(site)
ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync()
Console.WriteLine(site.Url.ToString())
```

Comment: First of all, we can use Ms graph api for sharepoint to list all the files in a site, please refer to this [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#http-request). `/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children` should help. Then we need to use this api into our code, in the API document it contains code snippet, and we need to create auth provider before calling this api . According to your code snippet, it looks like you are now trying to use password and user name to do the authentication,

Comment: then this auth provider might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#usernamepassword-provider   However this is not recommended, because it not a good idea to hard code user name and password in our code.